# Swift SpriteKit PhysicsBody forced as optional by Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, flappy-bird-clone

im having the following issue trying to code a flappy birds clone in Xcode 6 beta 7 with Swift and SpriteKit.

After I add the physicsBody property to a SKSpriteNode I cannot change a property of physicsBody directly, for instance I cannot do the following:

```
bird = SKSpriteNode(texture: birdTexture1)
bird.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.8, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
bird.runAction(flight)
bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bird.size.height/2)
bird.physicsBody.dynamic = true
bird.physicsBody.allowsRotation = false
```

Xcode build will fail with errors on the two lines where i add dynamic and allowsRotation values to PhysicsBody, the only way I can do it is by doing the following:

```
bird.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
bird.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
```

The issue of having physicsBody as optional with the '?' character is that it makes it complicated to do certain operations when trying to manipulate some bird physics I wanted to add, like rotation when moving.

Any suggestion on how to avoid / fix having to mark the physicsBody property as optional? ('physicsBody?')

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of issue]
<sub>(source: [tinygrab.com](http://new.tinygrab.com/1afb7d57d73040945157fec7b418aa2caed4a72acd.png))</sub>

[image: Zoom Screenshot of issue]
<sub>(source: [tinygrab.com](http://new.tinygrab.com/1afb7d57d7c7502078cab3568b6dc36285cc8dea51.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Actually,this problem has a simple way to fix it.
You can add ! after the physicsBody like this

```
bird.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
```

Reason:
Inside the SKNode code,you will see this statement:

```
var physicsBody: SKPhysicsBody?
```

The physicsBody is a Nullable Type.So XCode does check to prevent you unwrap the nil value.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it creating a object for the SKPhysics body and assigning it to the Sprite AFTER configuring it:

```
let body = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bird.size.height/2)
body.dynamic = true
body.allowsRotation = false

bird.physicsBody = body
```